# Align a view to the right (appcelerator alloy)

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am trying to align the view to the right, I tried

right="0"
I tried getting the width on the controller and subtracting the view size and no succes

```
<View id="logoutAlignRightContainer" layout="horizontal" width="33%" heigh="40dp" right="0">
  <View id="logoutAlignRight" left="" width="72dp" height="40dp" right="0">
  <Label left="3"  class="button" onClick="logoutEvent" width="Titanium.UI.SIZE">Log Out</Label>
</View>
```

I want to layout the $.logoutAlignRight to the right, but it stays at the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the layout=horizontal from logoutAlignRightContainer. By adding that you force the child view to layout starting from the left...

Answer (score 1):

The answer for your question is **Composite layout**, please read the below basics:

There are three types of layout in Titanium (let's suppose there are 3 child views A, B, C):

1. **composite** (default) - It always keep all child views at its center position, and that's why you can always use any of the property like **left**, **right**, **top**, **bottom**.
   So, A, B, and C will be at same center or on top of each other.

   - If you set only **top** and **bottom**, then it will only determine the height of view.
   - If you set only **left** and **right**, then it will only determine the width of view.
2. **vertical** - It aligns child views in a stack form,  one below another. Still you can use **left**, **right**, **top**, **bottom**, but you will find setting **left** and **right** property easy, but **top** and **bottom** properties might not behave as you expect because **top** and **bottom** will behave in relation to the other child views.

   - So if you set **left** or **right**, view will be left/right aligned staying in accordance with the stack form.
   - If you set both **left** and **right**, then it will be the width of view.
   - If you set **top**, then it will be counted from the parent's **top** edge.
   - If you set **bottom**, then there will be bottom space of same value but the child view will still be there at the top or at the corresponding position in the stack.
3. **horizontal** - Aligns views from left to right.

   - If you set **left**, it will add space to the left edge of view.
   - If you set **right**, it will add space to the right edge of view still keeping the view aligned from left, so its useful when you want to set the width of view in horizontal layout.

You should try these layout basics so that you can save your valuable hours in further development and soon you will be able to design efficiently. Titanium Docs are of great help.

Comment: Many thanks I'v read all the documentation, but I wasn't finding the error, and it was right there, in this excerpt and Ray pointed it out, many thanks again, I will try to stick to the documentation more.

Comment: Yes, most of the basic issues which we usually find weird sometimes, have their solutions right in front of us. As Ray had already pointed out the solution, I tried to gave you more collective insight based on my experience.